# to extract data between two words for the first occurence of a xml file in unix

Tags: bash, unix

How to extract data between "so" and "again"  ( the first occurence of test )

```
cat > sedtesting.txt

this is for testing
so test
AAgainn  and again
this is for testing
so test                   
AAgainn  and again
```

expected output is :

```
so test
AAgainn  and again
```

but what i am getting is :

```
so test
AAgainn  and again
so test
AAgainn  and again
```

in the below sample code we need to extract data between  "Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D"  and "Tracing Level"

below sample code

```
                        <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Expression" VERSIONNUMBER ="15">
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="&apos;UNKNOWN&apos;" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="CONTRACT_NUM" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="CONTRACT_NUM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="120" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="-999" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="MASTER_AGREEMENT_NUM" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="MASTER_AGREEMENT_NUM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="255" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="string" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="DEAL_NUM" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="DEAL_NUM" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="50" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="FUNDING_DT" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="FUNDING_DT" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="29" SCALE ="9"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="TO_DATE(&apos;1/1/1900 00:00:00 &apos;,&apos;MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS&apos;)" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="BOOK_DT" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="BOOK_DT" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT/OUTPUT" PRECISION ="29" SCALE ="9"/>
                        <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Normal"/>
                          <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="Exp_SEQ_CDL_CONTRACT_D" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Expression" VERSIONNUMBER ="8">
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="V_CNT+1" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="V_CNT" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOCAL VARIABLE" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="IIF(V_CNT=1,:SP.GET_MAX_VALUE(&apos;CILDL.CDL_CONTRACT_D&apos;,&apos;CONTRACT_KEY&apos;),V_MAX)" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="V_MAX" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="LOCAL VARIABLE" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="ERROR(&apos;transformation error&apos;)" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="V_CNT+V_MAX" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME ="CONTRACT_KEY" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="OUTPUT" PRECISION ="38" SCALE ="0"/>
                        <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="decimal" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="Lkp_CONTRACT_KEY" EXPRESSIONTYPE ="GENERAL" NAME =
                    <TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME ="Tracing Level" VALUE ="Normal"/>
                            <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" INSTANCEID ="16" NAME ="Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" REUSABLE ="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Expression" TYPE ="TRANSFORMATION"/>
                    <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" INSTANCEID ="17" NAME ="Lkp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" REUSABLE ="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="Lkp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" TRANSFORMATION_TYPE ="Lookup Procedure" TYPE ="TRANSFORMATION"/>
                    <INSTANCE DESCRIPTION ="" INSTANCEID ="18" NAME ="Rtr_CDL_CONTRACT_D" REUSABLE ="NO" TRANSFORMATION_NAME ="Rtr_CDL_CONTRACT_D" 
                    <MAPPINGVARIABLE DATATYPE ="date/time" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" ISEXPRESSIONVARIABLE ="NO" ISPARAM ="YES" NAME ="$$LAST_EXTRACT_DATE" PRECISION ="29" SCALE ="9" USERDEFINED ="YES"/>
                   </WORKFLOW>
            </FOLDER>
            </REPOSITORY>
            </POWERMART>
```

Comment: Why would you use a useless cat?

Comment: hi jens dat is jus for sample actually i have a XML file so i used cat

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F 'Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D|Tracing Level' '{print "\"Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" $2 "Tracing Level\""; exit}' RS= file.xml
```

OR `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '"Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D[\s\S]*Tracing Level"' file.xml
```

Comment: i applied the same to my XML but it is not working :(

Comment: even the for the above even

Comment: Oh so you have newlines also?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of input XML file in your question?

Comment: hi anubhava   im not able to upload that xml it is showing some code error something like that..

Comment: You don't need to upload whole XML. Just a small workable sample would be good. Also you need to edit your question and place XML in code blocks.

Comment: hi anubhava i have kept the sample code and add the requiremen for that xml code

Comment: hi anubhava   i am checking only for the first occurance             grep -oP '"Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D[\s\S]*Tracing Level"' file.xml             here it will start with "Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" but even if it finds "Tracing Level" for the first occurance many ocurance are present it is taking the last one and giving me the data till the last occurence of "Tracing Level"

Comment: i have given you sample ryt in the actaull file many occurance will be present for "Tracing Level" but it should pick the first occurance of the word "Tracing Level"

Comment: command is :  awk -F 'Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D|Tracing Level' '{print "\"Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_D" $2 "Tracing Level\""; exit}' testingfull.txt 
but output is :"Exp_CDL_CONTRACT_DTracing Level"  it is giving only two words as output

Comment: If you can reproduce that file in a file then I can also debug this.

Comment: sure but the xml is big where can i attach that file here

Comment: email me file on `anubhava[AT]aol[DOT]com` and I will work on it tomorrow as it is pretty late now.

Comment: ok sure an thanks 2mrow mrng it self i will send it Gud Nyt  mail will be from reddy257[AT]gmail[DOT].com